# MongoDB: will replica set sync delay also delay drop database commands?

Tags: mongodb

Will a delayed sync replica set member protect me from dropped database?
Will the drop database sync across members of a replica set immediately - or will I have the sync delay time to take the delayed member offline and save the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the docs carefully actually might help sometimes:

> Because delayed members are a “rolling backup” or a running “historical” snapshot of the data set, they may help you recover from various kinds of human error. For example, a delayed member can make it possible to recover from unsuccessful application upgrades and operator errors **including dropped databases and collections**.

[Delayed Replica Set Members](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-delayed-member/)